# com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (',' (code 44))

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to parse a JSON String `[-31.410115899999994,-64.1932632,0.0,,,0.0,134.0]`

```
 ObjectMapper mapper2 = new ObjectMapper();
List<Object> locDetails = mapper2.readValue("[-31.410115899999994,-64.1932632,0.0,,,0.0,134.0]", List.class);
```

using Jackson.

But getting the following error:

```
  com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: [-31.410115899999994,-64.1932632,0.0,,,0.0,134.0]; line: 1, column: 39]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1581)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:533)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:462)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1624)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:689)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:239)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:217)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3736)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2726)
```

Comment: Since this isn't a valid JSON in the first place, what do you expect?

Comment: then how to cast a string like this to an object[]?

Comment: may I know the proper reason of down voting?

Comment: [How to split a comma-delimited string into an array of empty strings](//stackoverflow.com/q/22350683)